# How can I build Custom request permission UI while using FCM on web?

Tags: firebase, push-notification

I am using firebase to send push notifications to the users on web.
but while requesting permission to the user the UI is looks like this.
[image]

but I want to build some custom UI like this.
[image]

to do that what I have to do?
can anyone explain with the code or refer any documentation?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions UIs are managed entirely by the browser -- they aren't something that can be modified. I'm guessing that if you click the "Allow" in the "Breaking News" widget you shared, you'll end up seeing the same browser prompt as the first screenshot.

It's actually quite important that these *not* be developer-modifiable, since bad actors could then create deceptive permissions dialogs and trick users into allowing things they didn't intend to allow.

Answer (score 0):

This is delayed, but still. I dont think it is wrong to have a custom UI for notifications. In fact google recommends this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/permission-ux

=== use Onesignal. They do it for you. (https://onesignal.com/)